# Bootstrap dropdown selection makes screen jump

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

So I'm using bootstrap for my website and I have many div's on each page with a dropdown on each that change the information inside the div from a chart to a table and vise-versa. This works fine except when the user selects an option from the drop down the screen seems to "jump", putting that div at the top of the screen. I found a similar issue for someone else saying it has something to do with the anchor tag(#), but I believe I need mine since the drop down does refer to something.

DROPDOWN:

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn  btn-warning dropdown-toggle btn-xs" type="button" id="dropdownMenuGraphOneSmall" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Graph One Options<span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuGraphOneSmall">
      <!--DROPDOWN MENU-->
      <li role="presentation">
         <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#graphOneData">Data</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
         <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#graphOneChart">Chart</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
         <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enlargeGraphOneModal" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Maximize</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
         <a class="collapse-link" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#graphOneCollapse">Collapse</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CONTENT IT CALLS:

```
<div class="content active row" id="graphOneChart">
    ............
</div>
<div class="content" id="graphOneData">
     ............
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an anchor tag, `<a>`, it is going to automatically go to the location that the `href` tag is pointing to. If your link is pointing to an id on the page, the link is going to scroll the screen to the element the link is pointing to. If you want to use the link to call a function, leave the `href` attribute empty, `href=""`.

Comment: I tried this but the page would reload and the view i selected wouldnt be in the div

Comment: Sorry, in the JavaScript, you have to prevent the default action of the link. Add an `onclick` listener. Should look like this `function(e){e.preventDefault(); //code here}`. That should stop the page from reloading, and then you can load the necessary content.

Comment: Use this code here in an init function or a `script` tag at the bottom of the page. `document.getElementById("link-to-stop").addEventListener("click", function(e){e.preventDefault()});`

Comment: so what would i be putting inside the function?

Comment: You only need `e.preventDefault()` in the function to stop the link. If you have any other processing that needs to happen after the link is clicked, put it after the `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Im just curious, is there a way to have a single line of javascript for all the anchor tags? As of right now i got this to work but i have to create a new javascript for every anchor tag since they need a different ID

Comment: Instead of using id's on all of the anchor tags, use a class. Id's are a unique identifier, but you can reuse a class as many times as you want. Then you can use the class to select the anchor tags. jQuery CSS selectors are great for that, or you can write the `onclick` attribute inline on all of the anchor tags.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the page from jumping, you can remove the href="" altogether, and just keep the a tag empty like this `<a>`, then it wont jump.

If you have to keep the href tag, you can use the `e.preventDefault()` in your `click` or `on` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a hash `#` in an anchor, the browser will automatically scroll to the element with the corresponding id.

For example, clicking on:

```
<a href="#graphOneData">Data</a>
```

Will cause the page to jump to:

```
<div id="graphOneData"></div>
```

To stop this happening, either change the id of the div or the href of the anchor.

Comment: When i do this the button doesnt open up the content inside the div